# Partitions of $64$ with summands less than $12$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

*How many ways are there to write $64$ as a sum of $10$ natural numbers (without $0$) such that each number is $\le 12$ (here, the order of these natural numbers doesn‘t matter)?*

My first idea would be to fill up to any sum between $52$ and $63$ using only $9$ numbers. Afterwards, the tenth number is fixed. However, I don‘t know how to count the fill-up and there might be duplicate counts.

(This is problem #15 from [Arnold‘s *Problems for children from 5 to 15*](https://imaginary.org/sites/default/files/taskbook_arnold_en_0.pdf), so I don‘t expect that a solution involves complex results about partitions.)

Comment: Ooh, the order of the numbers not mattering makes this problem a LOT harder. Oof

Comment: There can't be an odd number of odd numbers...

Comment: Arnold here is [V.I. Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold).  The introduction says (in part) "Most of them do not
require any special knowledge beyond the general education. However,
solving some of them may turn out challenging even for professors."  So I take it that the problem *statement* can be easily understood, but it does not imply the solution can be easily found.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Not correct. Notice that OP mentioned that ordering of naturals doesn't matter. If it did, one could easily solve with stars and bars.

Comment: The original wording of the problem is "How many ways are there to break up the number 64 into 10 natural summands (integers ≥ 1), whose maximum is 12?"  A straightword interpretation is that the largest of these summands must equal $12$, which makes the problem a little easier.

Comment: I've read the question as saying summands must be between 1 and 12 inclusive, not 12 is always the largest summand.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can deal with the order not mattering by ordering in non-decreasing order.

In other words, we choose each number by choosing how much larger it should be than the previous number.

So, we are picking numbers $b_0,...,a_9$ such that $b_0>0$, $a_1,...,a_9\geq0$, and such that $b_0+(b_0+a_1)+(b_0+a_1+a_2)+...+(b_0+...+a_9)=10b_0+9a_1+...+a_9=64$. For the sake of symmetry, we let $a_0=b_0-1$, giving us the equation $$10a_0+9a_1+...+a_9=54$$where $a_0,...a_9\geq0$ and $a_0+a_1+...+a_9<12$.

Can you solve this from here? It's a bunch of casework (I promise it is not as bad as it looks). The answer should be 9673.